# Тип захваченной переменной

Tags: c++

Следующий код, скомпилированный в VS2015, вызывает конструктор копирования `Foo` при захвате `foo`:

```
void bar(Foo& foo) {
    auto f = [foo]() {

    };
}
```

Ранее, ошибочно полагал, что внутри лямбды, `foo` должна была остаться ссылкой, по аналогии с обычными функциями:

```
template<typename T> void f(T foo) {
    // здесь доступен исходный объект foo, который был создан при вызове baz(Foo());
    // в случае, если это была бы лямбда с захватом foo по значению, здесь получается копия
}

void bar(const Foo& foo) {
    f<const Foo&>(foo);
}

baz(Foo());
```

Не разобрался в спецификации до конца, правильно ли понял, что при захвате по значению будет создана константная переменная (с помощью конструктора копирования), доступная внутри лямбды, имеющая тип `Foo`, не зависимо от того является внешняя переменная ссылкой на `Foo` или экземпляром `Foo`.

**update**

Что интересно, если вызывать не `f<const Foo&>(foo);` а просто `f(foo)` (второй пример кода), то шаблон инстанцируется типом `Foo`, а не `Foo&`. Т.е. при автоматическом выборе типа компилятор не различает ссылка это или экземпляр.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Чтобы разобрать Ваш пример, нужно обратиться к стандарту и понимать, что для реализации лямбда-функций компилятор создаёт тип-замыкание. Так вот, когда в списке захвата, некий объект закхватывается по значению, тогда в замыкании создаётся объект такого же типа, какой имеет этот объект, если это не ссылка. Если же это ссылка, то типом в замыкании будет тип, на который эта ссылка ссылается.

*Стандарт [expr.prim.lambda]p15:*

> An entity is captured by copy if it is implicitly captured and the
>   capture-default is = or if it is explicitly captured with a capture
>   that is not of the form & identifier or & identifier initializer. For
>   each entity captured by copy, an unnamed non-static data member is
>   declared in the closure type. The declaration order of these members
>   is unspecified. **The type of such a data member is the type of the
>   corresponding captured entity if the entity is not a reference to an
>   object, or the referenced type otherwise.** [ Note: If the captured
>   entity is a reference to a function, the corresponding data member is
>   also a reference to a function. — end note ] A member of an anonymous
>   union shall not be captured by copy

Таким образом, в замыкании Ваш `foo` будет иметь тип `Foo`.

Comment: Для простых типов (int&, boolean& вместо Foo&), стоит ожидать такого же поведения?

Comment: @VladimirGamalian, это не зависит от типов, так что — да

Answer (score 4):

Да, вы поняли верно. Вы захватываете `foo` *по значению*, так что в лямбде создается *копия* значения `foo` по данной ссылке.

Если захватите как `[&foo]`, то это будет захват по ссылке, т.е. в лямбде будет обычная ссылка.

**Update**
О типах.

```
void bar(int& foo) {
    cout << typeid(foo).name() << endl;
    auto f = [foo]()
    {
        cout << typeid(foo).name() << endl;
    };
    f();
}
```

Этот код утверждает, что `foo` в обоих случаях имеет тип `int`.

Если воспользоваться методом Мейерса, то код

```
void bar(int& foo) {
    TD<decltype(foo)> foo1Type;
    cout << typeid(foo).name() << endl;
    auto f = [foo]()
    {
        TD<decltype(foo)> foo2Type;
        cout << typeid(foo).name() << endl;
    };
    f();
    auto g = [&foo]()
    {
        TD<decltype(foo)> foo3Type;
        cout << typeid(foo).name() << endl;
    };
    g();
}
```

дает сообщения об ошибках с типами `int&`, `int` и `int&`. Так что, скорее всего, `foo` при передаче по значению хранится как `int`. Впрочем, чего т следовало ожидать.

Comment: Т.е. неправильно считать, что при захвате по значению тип переменной не меняется?

Comment: @VladimirGamalian: Я бы сказал, что тип не меняется, но без `&` захватывается не оригинал, а копия переменной. Но нужно экспериментировать.

Comment: Разве типы `Foo` и `Foo&` не разные?

Comment: Ну, например, вас же не удивляет, что rvalue при передаче в функцию становится lvalue? Это тоже изменение типа... С другой стороны, с этими ссылками сейчас сам черт ногу сломит... Надо бы Мейерса почитать, чтоб вам точно ответить.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian: Хороший вопрос, не знаю, какой именно тип `foo` внутри лямбды.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian См. дополнения в ответе.

Comment: @ixSci Дайте ссылочку, чтоб не искать - интересно посмотреть...

Comment: Кстати, если `decltype(foo)` внутри лямды, тогда он даст тип `foo` извне, а не внутри неё, т.к. это не является odr-use. С другой стороны `decltype((foo))` даст тот тип, который имело бы `foo`, если бы было захвачено в замыкание